How do I calculate the correlation of a variable between groups?
I have a question about calculating correlation in spss.
I am part of a group in which we ran an experimental study in which there were three conditions (so we have three groups: 1, 2 and 3).
One of the main hypotheses is related to the variable "Time".
So I have a database with the variable "Time" and the variable "Group".
I would like to know if I can or how to calculate the correlation between the time of group 1, the time of group 2 and the time of group 3.
I have already tried to create new variables with "compute variable" (so group time 1, group time 2 and group time 3) but when I try to correlate these three variables with each other the output table of correlations says that one of the variables is a constant.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I'm also adding a picture of my table:

And a picture of my data:


Hi, so are the observational units in groups 1, 2, and 3 all different? E.g. if you are measuring people, are people in groups 1, 2, and 3 all different people? And what kind of variable is "time" and how was it measured?

Could you please explain by this triple form of "correlation"?

So, if they are different participants/different observational units, correlations between "time group 1" and "time group 2" etc. don't make sense, because for a correlation you need matching observations for both variables you correlate with each other. How would you decide which observation from group 1 goes together with which observation from group 2 etc.?

Part 1: Yes, each group has different participants. The variable "Time" is an estimate of the time recorded by the participants on one task and is given in seconds (e.g. 30). I apologise if the question is pointless or too basic, I am only at the beginning of my studies. I am basically following the instructions I was given for writing the report, where all the variables that we show in the table with the descriptive statistics also had to be correlated with each other.

Part 2:  Since my table looks like this (photo attached), I assumed that I had to create correlations between groups as well. I assume from your answer that this is not possible?

It's possible that you are being asked to calculate the correlation between the differences in average time between groups, probably relative to group 1.
Each of these differences is a random number, with a variance and covariance with the others. Since correlation(D_i,D_j) = covariance(D_i,D_j)/(sd(D_i)*sd(D_j)), you can fill out that table using quantities that you can get from a regression.
Here's an example with automobile prices as the outcome, and repair record (1,2,3,4, or 5) as the group:
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. drop if missing(rep78)
(5 observations deleted)

. table rep78 , stat(freq) stat(mean price) stat(sd price) nototal

---------------------------------------------------------------
                   |  Frequency       Mean   Standard deviation
-------------------+-------------------------------------------
Repair record 1978 |                                           
  1                |          2     4564.5             522.5519
  2                |          8   5967.625             3579.357
  3                |         30   6429.233              3525.14
  4                |         18     6071.5             1709.608
  5                |         11       5913             2615.763
---------------------------------------------------------------

. regress price i.rep78, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         69
                                                F(4, 64)          =       3.69
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0092
                                                R-squared         =     0.0145
                                                Root MSE          =     2980.2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       price | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
          2  |   1403.125   1258.715     1.11   0.269    -1111.448    3917.698
          3  |   1864.733   710.8401     2.62   0.011      444.667      3284.8
          4  |       1507   488.8086     3.08   0.003     530.4925    2483.508
          5  |     1348.5   826.5883     1.63   0.108    -302.7999      2999.8
             |
       _cons |     4564.5   271.2901    16.83   0.000     4022.536    5106.464
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. /* relative to rep1 */
. margins r.rep78, post

Contrasts of adjusted predictions                           Number of obs = 69
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------
             |         df           F        P>F
-------------+----------------------------------
       rep78 |
   (2 vs 1)  |          1        1.24     0.2691
   (3 vs 1)  |          1        6.88     0.0109
   (4 vs 1)  |          1        9.50     0.0030
   (5 vs 1)  |          1        2.66     0.1077
      Joint  |          4        3.69     0.0092
             |
 Denominator |         64
------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
   (2 vs 1)  |   1403.125   1258.715     -1111.448    3917.698
   (3 vs 1)  |   1864.733   710.8401       444.667      3284.8
   (4 vs 1)  |       1507   488.8086      530.4925    2483.508
   (5 vs 1)  |     1348.5   826.5883     -302.7999      2999.8
--------------------------------------------------------------

. estat vce, correlation format(%9.2f)

Correlation matrix of coefficients of contrast model

             |     r2vs1.     r3vs1.     r4vs1.     r5vs1.
        e(V) |     rep78      rep78      rep78      rep78 
-------------+--------------------------------------------
 r2vs1.rep78 |      1.00                                  
 r3vs1.rep78 |      0.08       1.00                       
 r4vs1.rep78 |      0.12       0.21       1.00            
 r5vs1.rep78 |      0.07       0.13       0.18       1.00 

 

The last row tells you that the rep5 vs. rep1 price gap is most correlated with the rep4 vs. rep1 gap and least correlated with the rep2 vs. rep1 price gap.

Out of curiosity, where did the table come from? And why would it dictate what you need to do?
But, correlation is a pairwise analysis. You need matching observations to do it. For instance, if we want to know whether trait Extraversion and happiness are related, we have a bunch of people report both their Extraversion level and their happiness level. Then we can correlate the two variables together and if the correlation is positive we can say that those with higher Extraversion tend to have higher happiness. If we measure Extraversion in one group and happiness in another group and correlate the Extraversion and happiness scores, the resulting correlation does not mean anything.
Another thing is that you don't run correlations for overall means (well you might sometimes, but not in this case). You run them on individual scores. So, you'd need your data organized like this

id   time1  time2
1    3.3   2.5
2    1.8   1.0
3    0.7   1.1
4    2.1   3.5
etc.
where "id" would refer to a particular person, i.e., you'd have one row per person in your dataframe.

So even if you had same people measured three times and you wanted to correlate time1 time scores with time2 time scores etc. you wouldn't do it to the means (that you have in your table). You'd do it to individual scores. But in your case you can't do it because you only have scores for one variable (time) per participant.
Of course, if you also measured something else than "Time", you can perhaps correlate those other variables with your time variable.

Thank you for your reply, sorry maybe it's all a bit messy ; I've added a picture of what my data looks like. In the Group variable a certain number tells which group the participant was in, and then there is a Time variable which tells how many seconds the participant estimated. I've shown the table so that it might be clearer what correlations I'm interested in. I realise that it probably does not make sense then in my case to run correlations with my variables :).

Yes, it is as I expected. You probably want to investigate differences in group means. What would you like to accomplish with correlations?

It is basically just an instruction that we have been given for writing the report. That before analysing the data to test the hypotheses we should create a table of descriptive statistics and correlations between all the variables. I then ran into problems on the latter point in my own case. Specifically, my hypothesis tests for the existence of differences between means of the groups, and I managed to test this successfully! I will check with the tutor next week about my case, so that she can confirm that it doesn't make sense to calculate correlations. Thank you for your help! :))
